# Erro ao digitar o comando expo init my-project

Tags: react, expo

Alguém sabe como arrumar esse erro? ele acontece depois que eu executo o "expo init my-project".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá tive o mesmo problema e a solução encontrada com facilidade foi de alterar a politica de execução mas deixa o computador vulnerável. A solução que encontrei foi utilizar o npm start ao invés do expo start, ou você pode tentar rodar npm run expo start ou alterar o scripit de start no package.json do projeto claro desde que o expo esteja instalado e funcionando perfeitamente.

(aqui fala como alterar a politica por maquina usuário e etc...)
link para alterar a politica:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1

link de referencia expo:
https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-new-app/#starting-the-development-server

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo